# Understanding radial velocity dispersion

Tags: velocity, dispersion

I have to work with the radial velocity dispersion. Could someone help me to understand what this actually is and how I work with velocity dispersion? What happens if you multiply the radial velocity dispersion with the radius? Is this something that is often done? In which systems does the radial velocity dispersion change with the radius? How is it related to the velocity?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.